# Regex for substituting backslash?

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub

I have this:

```
a = "whut.\\nErgh"
```

What I want to achieve is:

`"whut.\nErgh"`  #sub 2 backslashes with 1 backslash

I tried this:

```
a.gsub(/\\\\/) { '\\' }
```

but it still returns me two backslashes.

Could someone please explain what went wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are not two backslashes in `"whut.\\nErgh"` but just one.

`"\\"` is just one backslash char, the first `\` is used to escape the backslash in a string.

If you want to convert `\\n` to a newline char, then use:

```
"whut.\\nErgh".gsub(/\\n/, "\n")
```

Comment: Right. I just tried "whut.\\nErgh".gsub(/\\n/, '\n'), but it didn't work. Do you mind to explain further?Sorry, just starting to learn ruby. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @user3363340 It should works, the result is `"whut.\nErgh"` and if you want to change the original string, then use `gsub!`.

Comment: Note that the character at index 5 of the result is `"whut.\nErgh"[5] => "\n"`, the newline character, not `"\"`.

Comment: Extra explanation: if you do `"whut.\\nErgh".chars`, you get `["w", "h", "u", "t", ".", "\\", "n", "E", "r", "g", "h"]`. You don't have a `\n` character in your text but rather the letter `n`. As @xdazz said, you only have one backslash in your text, which is `"\\"` (`"\\".length` returns `1`), hence his response =)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
"whut.\\nErgh".gsub(/\\n/, "")
```